# Context cascading Test

Tags: go

How to improve this `context` cascading test:

```
func TestParentTimedoutContext(t *testing.T) {

    ctx1, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    ctx2, cancel2 := context.WithTimeout(ctx1, 1000*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel2()

    time.Sleep(15 * time.Millisecond) // make ctx1 timeout

    if ctx2.Err() == nil {
        t.Error("failed")
    }
}
```

Command:

```
go test -timeout 30s -count=1 -run ^TestParentTimedoutContext$ my/internal/services
```

Output:

```
ok
```

Sometimes:

```
failed
```

go version go1.16.6

Comment: If you write tests that depend on races, they're going to be flaky. You suggest adding `runtime.Gosched()` after the sleep, but this just masks the problem, as would increasing the sleep time.

Comment: Sorry, not the sort of race in the memory-model sense. It's a race in the more general sense that there's two pieces of code that you expect to execute in a particular order (the cancelation of ctx2 and the `if ctx.Err() == nil` test, but there's no synchronization other than a soft one based on timing.

Comment: You can mock time with something like this https://github.com/benbjohnson/clock but it won't help if your code makes assumptions on the real time taken for some portion of the code to execute.

Comment: What you say is explicit synchronization is another piece of code that races with your test.   I guess you're testing some property of your code that depends on something that's not guaranteed by the context package, which puts you in the space of non-deterministic and flaky testing.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for `ctx2.Done()` and measure time duration which should be less than `ctx2` deadline.
Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/u9EPvAlffkG):

```
func TestParentTimedoutContext(t *testing.T) {
    t0 := time.Now()
    ctx1, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    ctx2, cancel2 := context.WithTimeout(ctx1, 1000*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel2()

    <-ctx2.Done()
    d := time.Since(t0)

    if d > 777*time.Millisecond {
        t.Error("failed:" + d.String())
    }
}
```

---

Benchmark:

```
func BenchmarkParentTimedoutContext(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
        go func() {
            ctx3, cancel3 := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10_000*time.Millisecond)
            defer cancel3()
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx3.Done():
                    return
                default:
                    // runtime.Gosched()
                }
            }
        }()
    }
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ctx1, cancel1 := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Millisecond)
        ctx2, cancel2 := context.WithTimeout(ctx1, 1000*time.Millisecond)
        <-ctx2.Done()
        cancel1()
        cancel2()
    }
}
```

Benchmark result (Linux):

```
# BenchmarkParentTimedoutContext-8  589  17_178_588 ns/op  // 17ms
```

---

Histogram code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    const n = 1_000
    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
        go func() {
            ctx3, cancel3 := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), n*time.Millisecond)
            defer cancel3()
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx3.Done():
                    return
                default:
                    // runtime.Gosched()
                }
            }
        }()
    }

    all := make([]time.Duration, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        t0 := time.Now()
        ctx1, cancel1 := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Millisecond)
        ctx2, cancel2 := context.WithTimeout(ctx1, 1000*time.Millisecond)
        <-ctx2.Done()
        d := time.Since(t0)
        cancel1()
        cancel2()
        all[i] = d
    }

    ave, x, y := histogram(all, 10)
    fmt.Println("min =", y[0])
    fmt.Println("max =", y[1])
    fmt.Println("ave =", ave)
    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOOS, runtime.GOARCH, runtime.Version())
}

func histogram(d []time.Duration, n int) (ave time.Duration, x []int, y []time.Duration) {
    x = make([]int, n)
    y = make([]time.Duration, n+1)
    min := d[0]
    max := min
    ave = min
    for _, v := range d[1:] {
        ave += v
        if v < min {
            min = v
        } else if v > max {
            max = v
        }
    }
    ave /= time.Duration(len(d))
    distance := (max - min) / time.Duration(n)
    v := min
    for i := range y {
        y[i] = v
        v += distance
    }
    y[len(y)-1] = max // compensate division error
    for _, v := range d {
        i := int((v - min) / distance)
        if i >= n {
            i--
        }
        x[i]++
    }
    return
}
```

Benchmark result (Linux):

```
go run .

min = 1.046524ms
max = 22.717866ms
ave = 2.090832ms 
[950 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 47 2] 
[1.046524ms 3.213658ms 5.380792ms 7.547926ms 9.71506ms 11.882194ms 14.049328ms 16.216462ms 18.383596ms 20.55073ms 22.717866ms]
linux amd64 go1.16.6
```